# Can I search for HTML meta tags?

Tags: html, search-engines

Is there a search engine that will allow me to search for specific HTML meta tag values?

Comment: if you could tell us why you want to search the meta tags, maybe we may have a better solution.

Comment: Questions on Web services and web apps are out of scope on SuperUser.

Answer (score 1):

Check if this combination of **Google** and [Sewatch](http://www.sewatch.net/) works for you.

I know the [cnet site](http://www.cnet.com/) has these meta tags:

> `<meta name="keywords" content="CNET, product reviews, tech reviews, tech news, free software downloads, CNET.com"/>`

So, if I '**Google**' for

> `site:http://www.sewatch.net "CNET, product reviews, tech reviews"`

I reach the [Sewatch cnet report page](http://www.sewatch.net/report/cnet.com),

> **cnet Meta Info**
>   **Title**
>   Product reviews and prices, software downloads, and tech news - CNET
>   **Description**
>   CNET is the premier destination for tech product reviews, news, price comparisons, free software downloads, daily videos, and podcasts.
>   **Tags**
>   CNET, product reviews, tech reviews, tech news, free software downloads, CNET.com

Note that this worked only because sewatch has published the meta so google could find it as content (not meta).

Does that work for you?
Have not seen even google directly let me search for meta -- would be interesting to know if that can be done.

Comment: Questions on Web services and web apps are out of scope on SuperUser. Please don't post answers on the same.

Comment: @Sathya, Well, the question was asked and I had something that might help, so is there any harm in posting an answer? I can understand your desire to educate about not posting the question. But, why refrain from a possible answer? You do have the option of flagging it towards a close, and the moderators also have the ability of closing it immediately.